# How to fix envoyproxy's validate rules proto dependency in Go repository with bazel build tool

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, bazel, envoyproxy

I am trying to use bazel and gazelle tools to build a large Golang repository with pre-generated proto files. There are issues in using validate rules from envoyproxy in proto definitions and the bazel tool fails to build repository with this dependency. To reproduce the issue, I have created a [github repository](https://github.com/ihtkas/bazel-gazelle-ex)  with a sample gRPC service. Without envoyproxy's validate proto dependency, the bazel tool succesfully builds the go packages. But introducing this dependency throws error.

Commands used to build the repository:

Generate proto files before building repository.

```
protoc -I=. -I ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate@v0.6.1 --go_out=./../../../ --validate_out="lang=go:./../../../" --go-grpc_out=./../../../ ./protos/pinger/service.proto
```

Use gazelle to generate dependencies

```
bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos -from_file=go.mod -to_macro=deps.bzl%go_dependencies -build_file_proto_mode=disable_global -prune
```

Use gazelle to generate BUILD.bazel files

```
bazel run //:gazelle
```

Build pinger go binary

```
bazel build //cmd/pinger
```

The last build command throws an error

> go/src/github.com/ihtkas/bazel-gazelle-ex/api/pinger/BUILD.bazel:3:11:
> error loading package
> '@com_github_envoyproxy_protoc_gen_validate//validate': Unable to find
> package for @com_google_protobuf//:protobuf.bzl: The repository
> '@com_google_protobuf' could not be resolved. and referenced by
> '//api/pinger:pinger' ERROR: Analysis of target '//cmd/pinger:pinger'
> failed; build aborted: Analysis failed

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/issues/988) for the same. There are multiple suggestions and none of them seems to work for me. Explaining all the attempts will make this question useless. I need help in finding one solution which will solve the issue and build the repository successfully with bazel tool with pre-generated proto files. Based on suggestion, I will experiment and share the results here or in the same repository.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be fixed by following three steps.

-> Use specific commit from envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate with the bazel [naming convention fix](https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate/pull/471)

```
go get github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate@4f41f10dde19ec4dd9dd8cf6f7537139f52fb58b
```

-> Include dependency for "com_google_protobuf" in bazel WORKSPACE

```
http_archive(
        name = "com_google_protobuf",
        sha256 = "d0f5f605d0d656007ce6c8b5a82df3037e1d8fe8b121ed42e536f569dec16113",
        strip_prefix = "protobuf-3.14.0",
        urls = [
            "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/v3.14.0.tar.gz",
            "https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/v3.14.0.tar.gz",
        ],
    )
    
    load("@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_deps.bzl", "protobuf_deps")

protobuf_deps()
```

-> Update io_bazel_rules_go to v0.28.0

All the fixes are included in a [PR and merged to a branch "working"](https://github.com/ihtkas/bazel-gazelle-ex/pull/1) in the repository for reference.